# Doubt on a probability question: Finding the probability of a man to die next year

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> **Problem Statement**: There are $n$ men $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ each aged $x$ year and the probability of each of
> them dying next year is $p$. What is the probability that $A_1$ will
> die next year and be the first to die?

I tried to solve it like this: 
Let $P(A_i)=p=$ probability of $A_i$ dying next year;  $P(\bar A_i)=$Probability of $A_i$ not dying next year 
Let $E=$ event that $A_1$ dies next year and is the first to die

$P(E)=P(A_1\cap \bar A_2\cap \bar A_3\cap...\cap \bar A_n)=P(A_1)(1-P(A_2))...(1-P(A_n)=p(1-p)^{n-1} \tag{1}$

Alternatively, let's consider $F=$ event that atleast one of the $n$ men dies. 
$P(F)=1-$ Probability that no one dies=$1-(1-p)^n$ and therefore, probability that $A_1$ is the first to die =$\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{n}\tag{2}$ (because each of the men is equally likely to die)

I wonder why both the answers in $(1)$ and $(2)$ are different. Please help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: Your $E$ is the event that he is the only one that dies, not that he is the first.

Comment: @YJT: I thought about a bag containing all different colored balls and then drawing balls one by one without replacement. I don't understand why $E$ is not the event that $A_1 $ dies and is the first to die.

Comment: In your event, you explicitly set the rest to stay alive, thus not covering all the options. How does the analogy to balls should work?

Comment: @YJT: I think that $A_1$ dying next year & being the first to die means that only he dies next year while the others stay alive. Right?

Comment: No, that's not right.  It means that he dies first among those who die during the year.

Comment: @saulpatz: That's what I want to find. What do you mean? Please explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1)$ Does not take into account the fact that multiple people can die in the same year and $A_1$ still be the first to die out of them. For example, if we know that $A_1$ and $A_2$ die next year, there is a $1/2$ chance $A_1$ died first, and a $1/2$ chance $A_2$ died first. If $A_1$ and $A_2$ die next year, and $A_1$ died first, that would not be a member of event $E$. Therefore $P(E)$ is not the correct answer to the problem. $(2)$ is correct reasoning.